# Incorrect stats_reset value in pg_stat_bgwriter

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-stat-statements

I am checking the stats of background process by below command:

```
select * from pg_stat_bgwriter ;
```

But after resetting the stats by command:

```
select pg_stat_reset() ;
```

I am expecting the column stats_reset return the time at which stats reset, but it shows the very old time. Any idea or guidance on this ?

Example output:

> checkpoints_timed | checkpoints_req | checkpoint_write_time |
>   checkpoint_sync_time | buffers_checkpoint | buffers_clean |
>   maxwritten_c lean | buffers_backend | buffers_backend_fsync |
>   buffers_alloc |          stats_reset
>   -------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------
>   -----+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------------------------
>                 2525 |               9 |             193751796 |               322501 |            3162662 |         30839 |  176 |          451310 |
>   0 |       4120735 | **2016-09-27 08:32:43.638545-05**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer in the documentation : [Doc- link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-BGWRITER-VIEW)

bgwriter is the shared among all the databases so it can be reset by different function by the below command:

```
pg_stat_reset_shared('bgwriter') ;
```